# Stay awake an adjective or an adverb?

Tags: adjectives

Stay awake, is awake here an adjective? my dictionary says so! but it sounds like an adverb.

Comment: Sounds like ... *adverb?*  How?

Comment: I don't think it would be an adverb here, seems like a simple adjective. It could be reworded as "Remain in a state of not sleeping". Consider that you could substitute any adjective for awake and have it still make sense: "Stay happy", "Stay awesome", "Stay asleep".

Comment: I know that an adjective describe a noun, but here stay is a verb and it makes sense, at least to me, that awake is an adverb that describes the state one is in.

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/adverb-or-adjective.1076708/

Comment: Consider also the sentence "She stayed awake fitfully". Here, fitfully is an adverb modifying awake. Awake continues to be an adjective.

Comment: I have never been confused like that. I still think it's an adverb John.

Comment: If you aren't going to listen to people telling you it's not, why did you post the question in the first place? :P

Comment: There's also the fact that adverbs are usually formed by adding "-ly" to an adjective, which obviously isn't the case here (I know that's not necessarily always true, but generally speaking if it doesn't end in -ly it's not an adverb)

Comment: I just want to understand that's it. Thank you John. I will read the thread you gave me.

Comment: Sara - I agree that *stay* is a verb, but a word that describes the state one is in, as you say, is an adjective.  The imperative here is to remain in a state of being awake, and the state is described by an adjective, *awake*, just as you could say "He is awake."  In the sentence "The plant must stay green", you wouldn't think *green* was an adverb, would you?

Comment: Certainly not an adverb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Awake, alive, asleep etc"  are predicative adjectives, ie they can only be used after linking/copula verbs like to be and similar verbs. They can't be used before a noun.

The prefix a- was originally a preposition like in, on or of. Asleep means in (the state of) sleep.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=A-

By the way there are several prefixes a- with different meanings eg anormal meaning not normal.  http://www.yourdictionary.com/a#websters

Answer (score 3):

The underlying meaning of **stay** and **remain** is "continue *to be*" and so they function like  copular verbs, which connect an adjective (or other noun complement) to a subject.